# finfo_file returns empty string

Tags: php, mime-types

I am trying to check the mime type of an uploaded file before I move it but I cannot get `finfo_file` to return anything.

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime = finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES['imageFile']['tmp_name']);
echo $mime;
// returns NOTHING!
```

...so just to test in finfo_file is available and the file path is good:

```
echo phpversion();
// returns 5.1.28

$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
foreach (glob("*") as $filename) {
    echo finfo_file($finfo, $filename) . ', ';
}
// returns text/plain, text/html, image/png, directory, text/x-asm, text/x-php, text/x-php, text/x-php, directory, directory

echo move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imageFile']['tmp_name'], getcwd().'/uploadsTemp/'. uniqid());
// returns 1
```

Can it be that somehow `finfo_file` cannot read the file?

Comment: What OS is this running on?

Answer (score 2):

Today I had the same problem and this was caused because the uploaded file was larger than the upload_max_filesize in php.ini.

I just notice it here since I could not find this solution in other posts.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, it (`finfo_file`) returns not just mime type, but text description of the contents of the file. [Visit.this.page](https://php.ru/manual/function.finfo-file.html)

Try to use this `$imageinfo['mime']`. Maybe it helps!

And there can be one suggestion, but I am not sure, why must you use `$_FILES['imageFile']['tmp_name']` instead of `$_FILES['imageFile']['name']`? Is it so important to use temporary file?

Answer (score -1):

This might be a stupid answer as there may be many reasons why you can't use this but...

Can you not just use `$_FILES["Img"]["type"]` and use the MIME types given by that?

Sorry if that doesn't answer your question.

Comment: $_FILES["Img"]["type"] cannot determine correct mime, and it can be spoofed